# When {% csrf_token %} may be inconvenient?

Tags: django

**Django 1.10**

In the documentation we can read:

> While the above method can be used for AJAX POST requests, it has some
>   inconveniences: you have to remember to pass the CSRF token in as POST
>   data with every POST request.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax

The mentioned "above method" is about adding {% csrf_token %} to forms.

And it is said in the documentation that more convenient may be:

```
function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
    // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
    return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
}
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        }
    }
});
```

Well, I can't catch in which case {% csrf_token %} may be inconvenient.

I tried:

```
<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}



function post_create(){

    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: '{{ object.get_frame_date_create_url }}',
        data: $("#object_form").serialize(),
        success: add_post_data,
        error: fail,
        });
}
```

Seems to be working. The result of $("#object_form").serialize() looks like this:

```
"csrfmiddlewaretoken=NFgXO1gsHJbi0N1IUb5ZPQ2rno2RGBrRR8kxboewWDC63sm2hxlvXtUtyviCSoZ1&date=2015-01-01&precision=F&frame=1"
```

What must I remember here? How can I forget to pass csrfmiddlewaretoken? It is just an ordinary field of the form. Hidden from users, but not from the programmer.

Is it supposed that there are cases when it is necessary to manually touch every field in the form and send it separately. I can't imagine that.

Your comment would be highly appreciated: **do I understand correctly that $("#object_form").serialize() is fine? And in which case it is more convent to use ajaxSetup?**

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking about here, the docs mention that it may be inconvenient because you have to remember to pass it in and it suggests that you include it in a separate header thats always included

Comment: I'm newbie in web development. This remark about ajaxSetup just astonished me. I can't imaging when it may be more convenient. Of course, this is not about one form. ajaxSetup means that there is a series of forms. So, what is it about? Does anybody manually traferses through fields manually without serialize() method?

Comment: But someone still had to add the `{% csrf_token %}` to the form, and this is saying that someone may forget that. so to ensure its always got one, put it in a separate header

Comment: Well, something becomes clear. This seems not to be the case of forgetting to add csrf_token, but the case of intentionally disabling CsrfViewMiddleware. Thank you. If you organize this as an answer, I'd gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's absolutely no reason why you need an HTML form to send a POST request. For example, both the upvote/downvote buttons and the favorite button on this page are simple buttons that send an AJAX POST request without ever touching an HTML form.

Submitting a form asynchronously is just one of the many use-cases for AJAX. If that is the only way you use AJAX, the code from the docs may not give you much of an advantage. However, if you use it for one the many other use-cases, it will be much more convenient.